# Where to check custom webapplication logs in wso2 carbon

Tags: java, log4j, wso2

Need help here..
I have developed a java application and configured logs using log4j. I have deployed this application in wso2 carbon. Can anyone tell me where to check my application logs in wso2 carbon??
I can see only carbon logs wso2carbon.log.. 
Where can i check my application specific logs??

Answer (score 0):

If you have your own log4j.properties file in your webapp, you can configure the location in it.

See this for more details.

https://docs.wso2.com/display/AS530/Customize+Logging+for+Web+Applications